# Always and never (riddle)

Tags: riddle

> It's always 1 to 6,
>
> it's always 15 to 20,
>
> it's always 5,
>
> but it's never 21,
>
> unless it's flying.

**What is it?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is it

> A 6 sided Die

It's always 1 to 6,

> It always lands on a 1 to 6

It's always 15 to 20,
It's always 5,

> The sum of all 5 visible sides (1 top and 4 on the sides) add up to 15-20.

but it's never 21,
unless it's flying.

> When you throw the die, you can see all 6 sides for a small moment which all add up to 21.

And when it lands, it is 5 again.

Comment: Correct ! Good job

Comment: Why "It's always 5"? cc @MemyselfandI

Comment: When a dice isn’t flying, the sides that are visible are 5 sides. @Randal'Thor

Comment: Ahhh, got it, nice.

Comment: I think it'd have to be a *standard* one, as there are many variations that break the riddle now. ;)