# Always $\&$ Never

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

*[This post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59948/always-and-never-riddle?rq=1) has the same exact title, but it is not related in any way apart from the fact that it is also a riddle; all my riddles are (hopefully) original and created by me.*

---

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *We are either black with white, 
>  Or we are white with black. 
>  The latter is believed despite, 
>  The skin our coats set back. 
>  
>  Our patterns are a fingerprint, 
>  Though we have not one hand. 
>  In zig-zags we will always sprint, 
>  With zeal that names our band. 
>  
>  We can be found where Nile lives, 
>  Especially the wild. 
>  In the movie, king forgives, 
>  And Marty reconciled. 
>  
>  Our favourite shapes include a stripe, 
>  Where lions think of grass. 
>  If we did not remain our type, 
>  We all could not bypass.* 
>  
>  ***What are we?***

A little hint: 
A plural or non-plural answer is acceptable, I am not too fussed. I mean, I like to have a balanced *mindset*, a bit like the *Yin and Yang*. 
 
 The title is also a clue.

Comment: ***A bounty was awarded below to @QuantumTwinkie with regards to [my previous riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68400/there-is-a-phobia-of-climbing-me-and-a-phobia-of-staring-at-me).***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> Zebra

We are either black with white, 
Or we are white with black.

> It will look the same.

The latter is believed despite, 
The skin our coats set back.

> I am not sure.

Our patterns are a fingerprint, 
Though we have not one hand.

> You can tell what they are by the pattern (the fingerprint), but they have hoofs.

In zig-zags we will always sprint, 
With zeal that names our band.

> The run and there is a band called [The Zebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_(American_band))

We can be found where Nile lives, 
Especially the wild.

> Africa

In the movie, king forgives, 
And Marty reconciled.

> From Riley in the comments it is Madagascar the movie.

Our favourite shapes include a stripe, 
Where lions think of grass.

> Savannah

If we did not remain our type, 
We all could not bypass.

> Endangered.

Title,

> I am not sure.

Comment: Very good! But quickly, before I say anything more, why can I not award you the bounty for answering my previous riddle? It will not allow me to, I think because I have already accepted your answer. Is this true, do you know?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is this way to let the puzzle have a good chance to get solved and noticed before it needs extra attention. :)

Comment: The movie is probably rot13(znqntnfpne)

Comment: Okay. Well, unfortunately, I have to wait $8$ hours before I can upvote (because I have reached my daily voting limit) and [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$V qvq abg rkcrpg sbe zl evqqyr gb or nafjrerq fb dhvpxyl! Lbh zvtug abg unir svtherq bhg nyy gur pyhrf naq ersreraprf, ohg lbh tbg vg (naq V qvqa'g xabj gurer jnf n onaq pnyyrq "Gur Mroenf" ohg gung pbhyq nyfb cnff, V fhccbfr). Tbvat sebz lbhe cerivbhf pbzzrag, V jvyy abg npprcg lbhe nafjre abj; V jvyy tvir gvzr sbe bguref gb nyfb nggrzcg ng fbyivat gur evqqyr.$]$ :D

Comment: @Riley you are correct :)