# You Can Find Me in a Pickle Jar, But Not if There's Cookies (By Far!)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I'm in a pillow, but not in a blanket; 
>  In a piano, but not in a crotchet; 
>  In a picnic, but not in a basket; 
>  Close to four, but far from a quartet. 
>  
>  I'm not for treasure, but am for the pirate; 
>  In a picture, but not in the camera; 
>  I'm not for a plane, but am for the pilot; 
>  How quickly can you pick up the answer?*

The answer might serve useful for my [*previous* puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68908/where-did-this-mysterious-note-come-from).

---

**Hint:**

> *You cannot put me on pizza, 
>  But without me it would not exist; 
>  Nonetheless, if you put margherita, 
>  Instead of pineapple, then I will be missed.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's

> Pi

I'm in a pillow, but not in a blanket;
In a piano, but not in a crotchet;
In a picnic, but not in a basket;

> The words "pillow", "piano" and "picnic" contain "pi".
>  "Blanket", "crochet" and "basket" don't.

Close to four, but far from a quartet.

> Pi is 3.14, which is close to 4.
>  The word "quartet doesn't contain "pi".

I'm not for treasure, but am for the pirate;
In a picture, but not in the camera;
I'm not for a plane, but am for the pilot;

> "Pirate", "picture" and "pilot" all contain "pi".
>  "Treasure", "camera" and "plane" don't.

Title: You Can Find Me in a Pickle Jar, But Not if There's Cookies (By Far!)

> "Pickle jar" contains "pi".
>  "Cookie jar" doesn't.

Comment: Either all my friends are bad at riddles, or you are amazing at them. It's about time I start making them a bit more difficult, particularly for this site. I mean, you have the answer, but you got it so quickly! I was thinking of writing the verse, "Half in purple, half in violet" to make it more ambiguous, but I believe you would have still found the answer. Although I spent a short while on making this riddle, great job! :)

Comment: Perhaps the riddle would have been harder if the thing we look for wouldn't have been right at the beginning of all the words that contain it.

Comment: @MOehm Yeah true. I will try making my riddles a little bit more "scattered", if you know what I mean.

Comment: Until the second-to-last line I was actually sure the answer would be rot13[gur yrggre c] :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted people to think. My friends guessed it was a Rot13$[$srngure$]$, and then one of them changed his answer to Rot13$[$fvyx$]$ because of that very line. None of them — not even one of my math(s) teachers! — answered it correctly... but you did :)

Comment: Here I was trying to decide if it was the letter p or the letter i. It was both! Haha.

Comment: Well, Saturdays are now very busy for me, so I am not going to be very active on those days... which is why I did not have time to accept this answer! Congratulations! :D $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 1):

> The answer to your puzzle is pi.

Comment: Make sure you hide the spoilers! Feel free to take the tour and earn your first badge!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the [Tour]!) Unfortunately, your answer lacks an explanation of why you think it is correct, so may be deleted. Answers should be a thoughtfully considered attempt to solve the puzzle that was posed, with an explanation of how you arrived at the solution and/or why you believe your solution is correct. We're looking for quality answers, not a one-line response containing the first thing that leapt to mind. Please take some time to look around and familiarize yourself with the kinds of answers that are well-received here, ideally before you post any more answers.