# The Pen is Mightier than the Sword

Tags: riddle, rhyme, anagram

This riddle is probably really easy, but I came up with a good rhyme, so I wanted to post it.

> Pen is mightier than Sword;
>   Sword knows this is true;
>   However, what Pen brings to fight,
>   Sword possesses, too!

What is pen's weapon of choice?

Comment: This reminds me of the hint in [this riddle of mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68908/where-did-this-mysterious-note-come-from), but the first line of your riddle is quite a notable quote :P

Comment: Total coincidence. I was quoting whoever originally said that. It's a common phrase.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's what I'm saying... who actually said that, though? Do you know? :D **Edit:** Nevermind. It was an English author by the name of *Edward Bulwer-Lytton*. As a matter of fact, the actual meaning of the phrase gives a clue to solving the puzzle!

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_pen_is_mightier_than_the_sword) says that it was Edward Bulwer-Lytton. He later apparently became a terrible writer; he also invented "it was a dark and stormy night"

Comment: How did he become a terrible writer and yet we use his quotes? Hahah... people :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pen brings

> "Word" to the fight, as pens can write. And "sword" has "word" in the name.

Comment: Close enough. I meant "words," plural, but I can't nitpick

Comment: Also hi; I was actually just about to post a riddle inspired by yours, but I have to wait 40 minutes for some reason.